# AWS GLUE job latency

Tags: aws-glue

How to reduce latency of glue job while uploading output file to S3..I'm trying to load output file to s3 bucket my job is taking 6mins to upload file and the file contains just 9000 records
can anyone please help me to minimise the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that 6 mins time of uploading file to S3 or full time of a job run?

If it's second case, probably, AWS Glue does not your solution. Because Glue setup Spark cluster from scratch everytime when job runs. 
You can try to reduce number of DPU down to minimal 2 instances. It will reduce number of computation instances need to be deployed while job's run.